# Jboss 6 for jee5

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee

I wanna use jboss 6 and jboss 5 on the same machine (of course, neither is online at same time ). Why? Because, I don't know jee5 apps can be run on jboss 6. Now, I use jee5 and jboss 5. And I want to migrate jee6 fully. Because of reason of compatibility, I have to use and run jee5 at the same time.

I have been located jboss6 and jboss5 on `C:` and set `JBOSS_HOME` environment variable for c:\jboss5. When I want to run jboss 6 with command `c:\jboss6\bin\run -c all` , jboss5 is run. Because of environment variable?

How can I run either? And what about environment variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jboss5 is run because of the environment variable as you guessed.

Just reset the environment variable to c:\jboss6 and you should be able to run jboss6.

If you want to run them both at the same time on the same machine, the easiest way to accomplish this is to make your host multi-homed (multiple ip addresses on the same machine) and have a hostname resolve to each address. You need to do something like this to prevent port conflicts (each jboss will use similar ports on the same ip address, which will cause the 2nd server to not startup).

So if this was on a home network, you could have an ip address of 192.168.1.100 for jboss5 and 192.168.1.101 for jboss6.

Now to start jboss5, set the environment variable and:

c:\jboss5\bin\run -c all -b jboss5

and to start jboss6, set the environment variable and:

c:\jboss6\bin\run -c all -b jboss6

Comment: Can I run jee5 apps on jboss 6? If yes, I could remove jboss5 completely